# Parsing free format text in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, parsing, nsscanner

My Cocoa app needs to parse free format text entered via NSTextView. The result of the process should be a collection of keyword strings which can then be displayed for review to the user and optionally persisted using Core Data.

I looked at NSScanner but from the samples in Apple's documentation it looks like it's not capable of presenting a list of keyword strings from a given string. Its focus seems to be more on finding a particular occurrence of a given string within another string.

Are there alternatives?

EDIT: To make this clearer: all words in the entered text are potential keywords, so basically all words delimited by spaces should be considered. Lets assume that the user can specify a minimum required length for a string to be considered a keyword to eliminate irrelevant words like "to", "of", "in" etc. Once the parsing is done, a list of parsed keywords should be presented (possibly using a table view). The user can then select or reject each keyword. Rejected keywords will be stored so the parsing can be made smarter as more texts are scanned.

Comment: This seems a bit underspecified. I'm sure NSScanner is up to the job, but without knowing, for example, how keyword string
 boundaries are indicated or how you know whether something is or isn't a keyword string, it's hard to tell you specifically how you'd go about it.

Comment: I elaborated on the problem. Hopefully more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely use NSScanner to do this. All NSScanner does is go through a string character by character. It is up to you to decide what the keyword boundaries are and to interpret them using the scanner.

I suggest reading more about NSScanner in Apple's [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147-BCIEFGHC).